# How can I Convert interface{} to sql.NullString, using reflection or otherwise

Tags: go

I have created a map[string]interface{}, and populated it as such.

```
sli := make(map[string]interface{})

    str := new(sql.NullString)

    str.String = "hello"
    str.Valid = true

    i64 := new(sql.NullInt64)

    i64.Int64 = 55
    i64.Valid = true

    sli["first"] = str
    sli["second"] = i64
```

This all populates fine but when I try and accessthe string from the sql.NullString element in the map I get a panic.

> interface conversion: interface {} is *sql.NullString, not
>   sql.NullString

Here is the code I am using to access the string...

```
temp := sli["first"]
    temptype := reflect.TypeOf(temp).String()
    if temptype == "*sql.NullString" {
        s := sql.NullString{}
        s = temp.(sql.NullString)
        s2 := s.String
        fmt.Print(s2)
    }
```

I have tried change the type to sql.Nullstring as the error suggested but it does not then see the if condition as true.

Comment: Anyone know why this was voted down I edited to use correct package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new()` creates a nil pointer to the type requested. So it's expected that you're creating a `*sql.NullString` rather than a `sql.NullString`.  Your options are:

1. Convert it correctly for the type:

   ```
   s = temp.(*sql.NullString)
   ```
2. Don't create a pointer:

   ```
   str := sql.NullString{}

   str.String = "hello"
   str.Valid = true
   ```

   which can be shortened to:

   ```
   str := sql.NullString{
       String: "hello",
       Valid:  true,
   }
   ```